# MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.0 hybrid app supporting Windows8 (tablet and desktop) environment - how to integrate code with SCM?

Tags: version-control, windows-8, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

I'm developing an hybrid app with MobileFirst Platform Foundation (MPF) Studio 7.0 and I have to share the MobileFirst project code to the SCM system. I found this link in the MPF 7.0 Knowledge Center that explains how to do the job for all the parts of the project, including the environments' native folder, except for windows8 tablet and desktop: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/r_integrating_with_source_contro.html.
Since I have to support that environment, what are the folders/items exclusions I have to set for correctly sharing the Windows8 native code to the SCM?

Thanks, Simone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider it the same as Windows Phone. In general you will want to put in your SCM all of the native folder.

Comment: Thanks Idan. Really, if a take a look to the Knowledge Center link I posted above, I see that for every native folder (e.g.: android/native/, ipad/native/ ...etc.) are *always* indicated some items or sub-folders that should not be shared with SCM. E.g.: for windowsphone8, the subfolder windowsphone8/native/www should not be shared. By the way, from your response, I assume that for Windows 8 I shouldn't put in my SCM the sub-folder windows8/native/www as well. Is it correct? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Because those files are generated on each build.

Comment: Ok. Then I'd suggest to put this missing information (about windows8) in the Knowledge Center so that the SCM integration will be covered for all the supported environments. Thanks, Simone.